# Drag files out of Browser and into filesystem

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, file-management

I understand that Gmail users in Chrome can drag attachments out of their email and into a sensible place in their filesystem (rather than what normally happens, which is that you get a link on your desktop)

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour in general? In particular, say, on Firefox? It would be extremely useful to be able to drag links out of webpages while browsing...

Comment: Yep - that's what currently happens.  And it makes sense with weblinks.  But when it's a link to a pdf or an image it would be great for the drag to trigger a download of that file to the relevant location...